# "No default Matlab path found" When trying to install packages

Tags: apt, dpkg

I'm on an academic license for using `mathematica`, so I need to be connected to my institute network through the VPN. By while installing i get the error.
I tried to run following command: `sudo apt-get install openvpn`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
openvpn is already the newest version (2.3.10-1ubuntu2.2).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libdbusmenu-gtk4 linux-headers-4.4.0-128 linux-headers-4.4.0-128-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-128-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-128-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up matlab-support (0.0.21) ...
No default Matlab path found. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing package matlab-support (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 matlab-support
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

A window is always popping up where i have to define the path for matlab.

[image: Package configuration MATLAB interface configuration The MATLAB interface needs to know where MATLAB is installed on this system. This can be specified as a single directory or, in case of multiple MATLAB installations, as a glob expression (any expression supported by bash, including extended pattern matching operators). If, for example, the MATLAB executable is installed in /opt/matlab76/bin/matlab, please enter "/opt/matlab76". If there are multiple MATLAB versions installed, you can enter "/opt/matlab*" or a similar expression. Only matches that really contain a MATLAB executable will be considered. Therefore, a glob expression may match more than just MATLAB installation directories without negative side effects. Location of MATLAB installation(s): OK CANCEL]

Comment: `openvpn` is already installed and up to date. The matlab error is unrelated. See below for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

To use the `matlab-support` package, you need to download and install [matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/downloads/).

**If matlab is installed**, run the following command to show your matlab path:

```
which matlab
```

This is the path you will need to input when you get the popup window.

**If matlab is not installed**, you have two options. **Option one:** you could [install matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/downloads/) (download and unzip the installer and then run the "install" file, you may need to use `sudo` to run the file). **Option two:** you could uninstall the `matlab-support` package.

```
sudo apt remove matlab-support
```

---

As for the VPN package, `openvpn` is already installed and up to date. The installation error is unrelated.

Comment: thank you thank you, your this command sudo apt remove matlab-support helped me to get rid of matlab support that was the main blockage to update my system and i face same issue when update the system as shown in the question